# Using C++ function templates for a group of functions

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement, optimization

I have different functions for square matrix multiplication depending on matrix size which varies from 8x8 through 20x20. The functions differ from each other because each employ different strategies for optimization, namely, different loop permutations and different loop unroll factors. Matrix size is invariant during the life of a program. My goal is to reduce the time to decide which function must be used. For example, a naive implementation is:

```
 if (matrixSize == 8) C = mxm8(A, B);
 else if (matrixSize == 9) C = mxm9(A,B);
 ...
 else if (matrixSize == 20) C = mxm20(A,B);
```

The time taken to decide which function to use for every matrix multiplication is non-trivial in this case. Can the appropriate function be called right away, perhaps using C++ function templates?

Comment: If `matrixSize` is a compile-time constant, then I fully expect an optimizing compiler to choose the branch at compile time, and generate machine code equivalent to a single function call. If `matrixSize` is not a compile-time constant, then templates won't help anyway - there's no getting around having to branch at run-time.

Comment: `The time taken to decide which function to use for every matrix multiplication is non-trivial in this case.` With all due respect, I find this difficult to believe. Have you actually measured this time, on a non-debug optimized build?

Comment: Thanks. I think matrix size can be made a compile time constant, since time to compile is negligible compared to time to run. Even though I haven't measured the time to branch, I can see it being a hit when the there are a large number of calls to this function - 100,000 or perhaps even more than that, in my application.

Comment: If it's not a compile time constant, then perhaps changing the logic to use a switch statement would help - though a good optimizing compiler might optimize the above in the same way as a switch.

Comment: Also, does the size vary form call-to-call to this bit of code or is it the case that the same size will be used many times? If the latter, perhaps this could be made a strategy that was instantiated as soon as the size is known. (If the matrix size is indeed invariant for the life of the program, then this would certainly be the case.)

Comment: In the simplest case: create a global variable `Matrix (*mxm)(Matrix, Matrix)` (adjust the types to taste). Once the size is known, set `mxm` to point to the corresponding function; you'd only branch this one time. Afterwards, just call `mxm`.

Comment: The size is indeed a run time constant and can be made a compile time constant too. I am thinking of doing #ifdef and defining the matrix size at compile time. But could you elaborate a little on the strategy that you mention here? Thanks.

Comment: Got it. Good idea to set mxm pointer at the start. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the matrix size is invariant for the life of the program, then you could use `std::array` of `std::array` for the type of the matrices. Then you could have one multiplication function and overload it for the different types that you support, and the selection will be done at compile time.

You could adapt this approach if you use some custom class for the matrices, and make it a template class where the size is a template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix size is known in compile time, you could have something like:

```
constexpr auto matrixSize = 8;
C = mxm<matrixSize>(A, B);
```

and provide specializations for any known size.

If you do not know the size at compile time, you could anyway have the functions stored in a map, like this:

```
map<size_t, function<matrix (const matrix&, const matrix&>> multipliers;
multipliers.insert(make_pair(8, mxm8));
```

and later use something like:

```
C = multipliers[matrixSize](A, B);
```

Comment: Thanks. Using a map is a good idea too. Much faster than the if-then-else block, and removes the constraint of a compile time option.

Comment: @Tania, actually using an unordered_map should be even faster.

Comment: @Tania: I think a map will actually be slower than an if-else block because it involves dynamic allocation. Instead of a map you could use a switch - case construction, which will often be optimized to a jump table by the compiler, which is better than a map here.

Comment: Thanks Chris, for the insight.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Though I agree with your comment, maintaining a if-else block can became a headache later. Having a place to initialize the map and adding stuff right there is simpler IMHO.