# Optimizing if-then-else statement in Fortran 77

Tags: if-statement, optimization, fortran, fortran77

For my C++ code, I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425721) about two days ago. But I realize now that I have to do the coding in Fortran since the kernels I write is going to be part of an existing application written in Fortran 77.  Therefore I am posting this question again, this time the context is Fortran. Thank you.

I have different functions for square matrix multiplication depending on matrix size which varies from 8x8 through 20x20. The functions differ from each other because each employ different strategies for optimization, namely, different loop permutations and different loop unroll factors. Matrix size is invariant during the life of a program, and is known at compile time. My goal is to reduce the time to decide which function must be used. For example, a naive implementation is:

```
if (matrixSize == 8) C = mxm8(A, B);
else if (matrixSize == 9) C = mxm9(A,B);
 ...
else if (matrixSize == 20) C = mxm20(A,B);
```

The time taken to decide which function to use for every matrix multiplication is non-trivial in this case, specially since matrix multiplication happens frequently in the code. Thanks in advance for any suggestion on how to handle this in Fortran 77.

Comment: Why does it have to be F77? You could use a select case or a function pointer to solve this, I don't think these would be any slower.

Comment: The time taken by the if statement should be negligible compared to the matrix multiplication. The best you could do would be to put the mxm functions in the same file such that the compiler will eventually be able to inline the mxm function. If you can't, ask your compiler to do inlining between different fies.

Comment: I see that there already an accepted answer, but I am wandering if for that size of matrices (max of 20x20) it is worth the work. Those matrices will fit in the cache of almost any computer of today making it almost insensitive to the optimization. Did you by any chance time and see any difference between you versions of algorithms?

Comment: @haraldkl: Its got to be F77 since the main application is F77 and I have no power to change that.

Comment: @AnthonyScemama: Thanks for the input.

Comment: @innoSPG: These are actually 3D matrices representative of tensors. And though for my experiments I set it to a max of 20x20x20, it could be greater than that, perhaps 40x40x40 etc. Anyways, I have seen improvements applying loop permutation and loop unroll even for sizes 10x10x10. Thanks.

Comment: As there is no such thing like a F77 compiler anymore, and F77 is actually mostly a subset of the newer Fortran incarnations, you can just use newer constructs in your code without changing the main application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If matrixSize is a compile time constant in a language sense (i.e. it is a Fortran PARAMETER), then I would expect most optimising compilers to take advantage of that, and completely eliminate a runtime branch.

If matrixSize is not a compile time constant, then you should make it one.  Facilities provided in later Fortran language revisions (modules) make it very easy to propagate such a runtime constant from a single point of definition to a point of use.

Note that conforming Fortran 77 is also conforming Fortran 90, and with very few exceptions, will also be conforming Fortran 2015.

Comment: matrixSize is indeed a Fortran PARAMETER. When I debug my executable, I find that the if-statements are getting evaluated.

Comment: If you can make sense of debugging your executable, then you haven't enabled anything like the compilers' full optimising capability, or you are using a compiler with incredibly weak optimisation.

Comment: I used "gfortran -g", but is there a way to know for sure that the branch is being eliminated, perhaps short of reading the corresponding assembly?

Comment: A simple test here (i obviously have no idea what your actual Fortran code is...) with gfortran -g -S results in assembly for the relevant scope that doesn't reference anything bar the procedure that is the target of the relevant will-always-be-selected if branch in the source.  Even if I had no idea what the various assembler mnemonics meant (which is pretty much the case!), that tells me that the compiler has eliminated the branch.  Try it with your own code.

Comment: Wanted to confirm that this is indeed the case. Only the relevant function ends up in the assembly. Thanks a ton.

Comment: If it's a compile-time constant, just use the preprocessor instead of Fortran to do the branch.

Comment: @Jeff Use of the preprocessor would be retrograde.  It offers no benefit (production compilers will do the necessary optimisation) but comes with non-negligible portability and complexity cost.

Comment: @IanH Please name a Fortran compiler that cannot preprocess if-elif-else-endif statements.

Comment: Some editions of LF95 are commercial examples.  Quite a number of source utilities will also not handle preprocessor directives out-of-the-box.  Preprocessing can always be provided by an external tool, but that is a complexity cost, on top of the typical source complexity issues that use of basically language-ignorant preprocessing brings.  Use of the preprocessor is a necessary evil in some situations, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If it is known at compile time, then you only need 1 version of this function.  It seems like you just put each version of the function in its obj object file or library, and then link to the appropriate one.

If you meant to say it is known at *runtime*, but does not change over the course or an execution, then you could have 13 versions of the code, one for each size, and use on set of ifs to decide which to use.

Comment: Wont it be a problem with a link time option to the appropriate object file, that the functions in each object file must have the same name, say, "mxm" to be properly referenced by the code?